# C++ move semantics with ostringstream

Tags: c++, move

If a function receives a `std::string&&`, is there a way to pass a `ostringstream` without creating a temporary stream with a full duplication of the underlying buffer?

Comment: Why can you not pass an `ostringstream&`?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Can you show some code?

Comment: Sounds like that will create a temporary string, not a temporary stream.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you have to copy the buffer, because it's not in the same structure that `std::string` requires, and there is no `std::string` move constructor that accepts `std::ostringstream&&`.  The `std::ostringstream::str()` method will copy the value of the buffer into an `std::string` instance.  Then you are free to move that string using a method that accepts `std::string&&`.